# For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x-3)^n}n$ approximate when x = 4, with an error that does not exceed .01

Tags: calculus, power-series, approximation

For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x-3)^n}n$ approximate with specific details the series when x = 4, but with an error that does not exceed .01. That is, find a value of n so that the nth partial sum of the series differs from the actual sum of the series by less than .01. (I've already shown that the power series converges for $2 < x \leq 4$ )

I know that $|S - S_n|<a_{n+1}$ So I assume that I need $|S - S_n|<0.01$, therefore, do I just need to find $a_{n+1}$ such that $0.01\leq a_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: In magnitude, but essentially yes.

Comment: @Ian is this more of a guess and check process rather than some sort of algorithm to find the answer then?

Comment: Not really. You need $|a_{n+1}| \leq 0.01$, but $|a_{n+1}|=\frac{1}{n+1}$, so...